# The gradient of the Frobenius norm under a similarity transformation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, control-theory, numerical-optimization

I am looking for the gradient of the following cost function

$||T^{-1}AT|| + ||T^{-1}BT||$

with respect to $T$. $A$, $B$ are real square matrices. $T$ is a coordinate change of corresponding dimension. The norm can either be Frobenius or L2 (either euclidean or spectral).

My problem occurs since the diagonalization transformation on $A$ or the jordan canonical transformation which minimizes its norm (under certain assumptions), can cause $||B||$ to explode and viceversa. I believe this is a very hard, impossible, problem to find global minima and I am looking into all mathematical insight and algorithms I could use to help me find a consistently a similar local minima

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's use a colon to denote the trace/Frobenius product,
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= {\rm tr\,}(A^TB) \cr
\|A\|_F^2 &= {\rm tr\,}(A^TA) = A:A \cr
}$$
And let's define the variables 
$$\eqalign{
 X &= T^{-1}AT &\implies dX = T^{-1}\big(A\,dT-dT\,X\big) \cr
 Y &= T^{-1}BT &\implies dY = T^{-1}\big(B\,dT-dT\,Y\big) \cr
 \alpha^2 &= \|T^{-1}AT\|_F^2 &= \|X\|_F^2 =  X:X \cr 
 \beta^2 &= \|T^{-1}BT\|_F^2 &= \|Y\|_F^2 =  Y:Y \cr 
}$$
Find the differential and then the gradient of $\alpha$
$$\eqalign{
 2\alpha\,d\alpha
 &= 2X:dX \cr 
 &= 2X:T^{-1}\big(A\,dT-dT\,X\big) \cr 
 &= 2T^{-T}X:\big(A\,dT-dT\,X\big) \cr 
 &= 2\big(A^TT^{-T}X-T^{-T}XX^T\big):dT \cr 
 &= 2T^{-T}\big(X^TX-XX^T\big):dT \cr 
\frac{\partial\alpha}{\partial T}
   &= \alpha^{-1}T^{-T}\big(X^TX-XX^T\big) \cr 
}$$
The calculation for $\beta$ is similar and yields
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial\beta}{\partial T}
   &= \beta^{-1}T^{-T}\big(Y^TY-YY^T\big) \cr 
}$$
So, if we choose the Frobenius norm, then your cost function $(\phi)$ and its gradient is given by
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \alpha + \beta \cr
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial T}
 &= \frac{\partial\alpha}{\partial T} + \frac{\partial\beta}{\partial T} \cr
 &= T^{-T}\Bigg(\frac{X^TX-XX^T}{\|X\|_F} + \frac{Y^TY-YY^T}{\|Y\|_F}\Bigg) \cr\cr
}$$
Note that the cyclic property of the trace gives us several ways to rearrange the terms in a Frobenius product. For example, all of the following are equivalent
$$\eqalign{
A:BC &= A^T:(BC)^T \cr
 &= BC:A \cr
 &= AC^T:B \cr
 &= B^TA:C \cr
}$$

Comment: I dont understand how the last step in finding the differential and then the gradient of $\alpha$ holds. How can $dT$ inside a frobenius product (i.e, inside a trace) come to the left hand side as a division?

Thank you so very much, this is great help!